# setTimeout method :displaying alerts in two different time intervals

Tags: javascript, settimeout, alert

I am trying to display the two alert box in two different time intervals

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
       setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);    
       setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello World")},3000);
}
</script>
```

I want to display Hello alert after 3 sec and Hello World after 3 sec of 1st alert, but 2nd alert displaying immediate to 1st one.

How to make it work?

Thank You

Comment: Why not move the second setTimeout into the function of the first setTimeout?

Comment: Better just change 3000 to 6000 in the second line

Comment: The difference is whether he wants the second alert 3 seconds after the first one pops up, or 3 seconds after the user clicks OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can nest a timeout in the function of the first one:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Hello");    
    setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello World")},3000);
},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the second setTimeout in the first one. Like this...

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Hello");
    setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello World")},3000);
},3000);
```